# Release File Error when setting up local/offline apt repository

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, repository

I'm trying to set up a local apt repository on XUbuntu as per the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Personal).

My debs folder has nothing but `.deb` files and the `Packages.gz` file generated by

```
dpkg-scanpackages . /dev/null | gzip -9c > Packages.gz
```

Running it gives me the following output:

```
dpkg-scanpackages: warning: Packages in archive but missing from override file:
dpkg-scanpackages: warning: (list of all the package names)
dpkg-scanpackages: info: Wrote 14 entries to output Package file.
```

I followed all of the same steps outlined by Ubuntu's guide, but when I run

```
sudo apt update
```

I get the following errors pertaining to my local repo:

```
Get:1 file:/path/to/debs ./ InRelease
Ign:1 file:/path/to/debs ./ Inrelease
Get:2 file:/path/to/debs ./ Release
Err:2 file:/path/to/debs ./ Release
  File not found - /path/to/debs/./Release (2: No such file or directory)
... (Other repositories doing things successfully) ...
E: The repository 'file:/path/to/debs ./ Release' does not have a Release file
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository configuration and user configuration details.
```

I'm not really sure where to go from here. I've tried a couple of different sites' guides on setting up local repos to no avail.

Edit: Not exactly sure what I changed, but apt is now able to find my packages. I tried running `sudo apt-get update` instead of `sudo apt update`, but that was the only difference I can see between this attempt and all the others. Weirdly, `apt` still gives me the same errors, but now the packages appear when I search for them.

Answer (score 0):

The "Release" file is a manifest of hash values represent packages' authentication information. By default `apt-get` require this info to secure the source of your system software environment.

You can just add `--allow-insecure-repositories` or `--allow-unauthenticated` to `apt-get update` to make it work, though security warnings will still be given by apt.